# Why is Vim not launching when passing arguments in its .desktop file?

Tags: unity, vim, .desktop

I have `vim.desktop` file in `~/.local/share/applications/` directory with these lines:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Vim Text Editor
Comment=Edit text files
TryExec=vim
Exec=vim
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Icon=terminal
Categories=Utility;TextEditor;
StartupNotify=true
MimeType=text/plain;
```

This `.desktop` file works fine at this point (i.e. I can search in Unity dashboard it and click it to open vim)

But I wanted more from this desktop file. I wanted to start it in insert mode, so I changed some parts of it, like:

```
TryExec=vim -c 'startinsert'
Exec=vim -c 'startinsert'
```

But as soon as I save this file I am not able to search it.

Comment: @WarriorIng64 This is not specific case for **vim**. This applies to all softwares.

Answer (score 1):

Try logging out/in or even restarting to fix this. The following `.desktop` file works perfectly for me:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Vim Text Editor
Comment=Edit text files
Exec=vim -c 'startinsert'
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Icon=terminal
Categories=Utility;TextEditor;
StartupNotify=true
MimeType=text/plain;
```

[image]

Comment: Fix in here removing TryExec line. Without logging off, it works.

Comment: @izx Hmm.. Its working. Can you tell me what is the role of `TryExec`? What does it actually does? Why is it even there in an `.desktop` file?

Comment: @izx And how is your dash yellowish? Mine is black and I don't find any way to configure it.

Comment: TryExec verifies the program is installed. http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s05.html